# I need help troubleshooting R studio Tidyverse Error Message

Tags: r, tidyverse

> library(tidyverse)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.9 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

This message appears after running command:

library(tidyverse)

Comment: Although this is the same error message, none of the suggestions are working for me

Comment: What version of `rlang` do you have installed? When you reinstall `rlang`, what version gets installed? What version of R do you have?

Comment: Also note that once you've installed a new version of `rlang` you need to restart your R session if `rlang` was already loaded to have access to the new version.